# SQL Query Getting First Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    TM09_Product.F09_ProductCode, TX42_KndCmd.F42_KndCmdNo,   
    TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode
FROM 
    TX42_KndCmd 
INNER JOIN 
    TM09_Product ON TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode = TM09_Product.F09_PreProductCode
GROUP BY 
    TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode, TM09_Product.F09_ProductCode, 
    TX42_KndCmd.F42_KndCmdNo
ORDER BY 
    TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode
```

The result of the query looks like this:

```
F09_ProductCode  F42_KndCmdNo  F42_PreProductCode
-------------------------------------------------
    1B28G048        A01257       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048        A01914       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048        A02283       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048A       A01257       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048A       A01914       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048A       A02283       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048B       A01257       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048B       A01914       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048B       A02283       1A1EP0000090
```

It seems to keep repeating the same set of values. In this case, I just want to show the first record of each group of `F09_ProductCode`.

The expected results should show:

```
F09_ProductCode  F42_KndCmdNo  F42_PreProductCode
-------------------------------------------------
    1B28G048        A01257       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048A       A01257       1A1EP0000090
    1B28G048B       A01257       1A1EP0000090
```

Can anyone guide on what changes should I make or look into?
Thanks.

Comment: Noted. I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign ranking to your `F09_ProductCode` by `Row_Number()` function :-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.F09_ProductCode ORDER BY
                            (
                                SELECT NULL
                            )) RN
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TM09_Product.F09_ProductCode,
               TX42_KndCmd.F42_KndCmdNo,
               TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode
        FROM TX42_KndCmd
             INNER JOIN TM09_Product ON TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode = TM09_Product.F09_PreProductCode
        GROUP BY TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode,
                 TM09_Product.F09_ProductCode,
                 TX42_KndCmd.F42_KndCmdNo
--ORDER BY TX42_KndCmd.F42_PreProductCode

    ) A
) AA
WHERE AA.RN = 1;
```

Result :

```
F09_ProductCode F42_KndCmdNo  F42_PreProductCode  RN
1B28G048        A01257        1A1EP0000090        1
1B28G048A       A01257        1A1EP0000090        1
1B28G048B       A01257        1A1EP0000090        1
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked well. Is there any simpler way to do this? I need to translate this into C# codes...

Comment: `var result = (from product in products
                          from kneadingCommand in kneadingCommands
                          where product.F09_PreProductCode.Trim().Equals(kneadingCommand.F42_PreProductCode.Trim())
                          select new CommonSearchItem
                          {
                              F09_ProductCode = product.F09_ProductCode, 
                              F42_KneadingCommand = kneadingCommand.F42_KndCmdNo }`